# Copy the modeling between two objects

Tags: modeling

I would like some help ...

I have a .blend file with two objects, two bodies, body A and body B.
Body A has more subdivisions than Body B.

I wanted the body B to assume the shape of body A, have some easier way to do this?

I did not do using clipping and then join because of the amount of subdivisions that is different.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: pictures of the two objects would be helpful.

Comment: See the image........................

Comment: have you tried the shrinkwrap modifier?

Comment: as eromod suggests, make sure the models have each scale and location applied and are overlayed on top of each other, and then use the shrinkwrap modifier on body b, and choose body a as the target.

Comment: @poseydon what do you mean you "did not do using clipping and then join"?

Comment: just realized that body a has no head, so you'd need to create a vertex group on a that does not include the head and use that in the shrinkwrap modifier.

Comment: Hi, I've been able to do with the shrinkwrap option in a group of vertices, thank you very much for the tips of all of you.

David, I was cutting parts of body A and joining body B with CTRL + J.